# Диапазон значения double и float в Java

Tags: java, float, double

В таблице диапазонов значений переменных (Java) Double и Float соответствуют значения от 1.7e-308 до 1.7e+308 и от 3.4e-038 до 3.4e+038. При это у Integer диапазон начинается с отрицательного числа, то есть с -2.147... 
Хотелось бы узнать почему так, если и Double, и Float могут быть отрицательными.

Comment: Не понял вопроса. «почему так» — как? Диапазоны как диапазоны, чем они вас не устроили?

Comment: Хотя перечитал и понял. Не знаю, откуда вы диапазоны float и double копипастили, но отрицательные числа туда тоже вполне входят

Comment: У double и float знак хранится отдельно от самого значения числа (в старшем бите), и приведённый диапазон относится к значению числа без учёта знака. При этом ещё стоит заметить, что в эти диапазоны не входит ноль. Под него выделены отдельные специальные значения. Причём из-за того, что знак хранится отдельно, ноль может быть положительным или отрицательным, такие дела

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Максимальное значение `double` задается константой:

```
public static final double MAX_VALUE=1.7976931348623157E308;
```

и как говорит документация:

> A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type double

В битах это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно знаку отведен отдельный бит. Соответственно диапазон значений будет равен от `-Double.MAX_VALUE` до `+Double.MAX_VALUE`- как нетрудно заметить из битовой маски `Double` - в таком формате невозможно представить точный `0`, а можно только `Double.MIN_VALUE=4.9E-324`

В противоположность ему целые числа в Java хранятся в т.н. [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) - он же *Two's Complement*, грубо говоря, отрицательные числа (в целом представлении) хранятся отдельно, а не через представление положительного целого числа и отдельно знака - примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]